# C++ Pointer Assignment Clarification

Tags: c++, pointers, variable-assignment

What is the difference when I have for example,

```
int var1, *ptr;
ptr = &var1; // the pointer ptr copies the address of var1, hence ptr points to var1?

int var1, *ptr;
ptr = var1; // ptr points to var1, but does not have the address of var1, so can not change the value of address var1? 

int *var1, *ptr;
*ptr = *var1; // copy value of var1 into the location pointed to by ptr?
```

are my comments correct ?

Comment: `int var1, *ptr; ptr = var1;` is ill-formed. The compiler should complain.

Comment: `*ptr = *var1;` is also ill-formed: `var1` cannot have `*` applied to it

Comment: The difference is that only the first is well formed.   The other two will not compile.   Your comment for the first example would be better as something like "the value of ptr is assigned the address of var1, hence ptr points at var1".    The comments for the second and third examples are both incorrect, and can be replaced with "The assignment is invalid".

Answer (score 0):

The second (`ptr = var1`) and third (`*ptr = *var1`) options are wrong.

In the second case, you are asking for `ptr` to point to an address that is written in `var1`. I.e. `var1` integer value will be interpreted as an address. Probably not what you want, and will cause compiler error or warning.

In the third case you are trying to dereference something that is not a pointer (`*var1`). Definitely a compiler error.

Comment: var1 is a pointer to int in the third case.

Answer (score 0):

```
int var1, *ptr;
ptr = &var1;
```

Take the address of the int variable `var1`, and assign that address to the variable `ptr`

```
int var1, *ptr;
ptr = var1;
```

Assign the *value* of `var1` to `ptr`. This requires a cast.

```
int *var1, *ptr;
*ptr = *var1;
```

Assign the value pointed to by `var1` to the value pointed to by `ptr`. (Note that as written, they both uninitialized pointers point to non-deterministic locations, which if they exist, hold undetermined values.)